# wcf hosted in a windows service and httpbindings

Tags: wcf, windows-services, wshttpbinding

I'm working on a wcf hosted inside a windows service. It works like a charm but now I need to reserve a specific hostname for this wcf just as IIS does.
To be more clear, my hosted wcf runs on a windows server machine which response to multiple dns name, but I need to let the wcf reachable only from one of these dns. If I was using IIS it would be achievable by setting a specific hostname within the http-bindings settings, but unfortunately, I can't manage my wcf like that.
To your knowledge, is there any way to reserve a specific hostname for a hosted wcf outside IIS?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

yes, you could do it by register the http endpoint at kernel level(http.sys) using the following commands

```
cmd:   ***netsh http add urlacl url=http://fqdn:port/urlpath user=serviceaccount***
```

Then only on that specific dns/hostname, your http service will listen.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but maybe I misspoke. I need to reserve a specific fqdn for a specific hosted wcf. If I use the urlacl command I will restrict the access to the specified user which is not my desire.
Let's make an example. I have 3 DNS:
- www.contoso.com
- hello.contoso.com
- wcf.contoso.com
What I'm trying to do is let the wcf to be reachable only through wcf.contoso.com. Is it possible without IIS?

Comment: thats what the above command does, the user account there is specify on which account you are running the service, perhaps you could ignore ( i'm uncertain on it). This what even iis does internally, you could check the iis website url using the same netsh command                                                                   *netsh http show servicestate*